# PhoneGap check network state

Tags: android, cordova, internet-connection

I created an android app using PhoneGap and I checked the network state to verify if the device is connected to internet or not. If the device is connected to the internet a button is activated otherwise it is inactive. I used navigator.connection.type but my problem is: if the device is not connected to the internet the button is inactive and when the device connects to internet the button state does not change, it remains inactive.
My code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
}

function onOnline() {
checkConnection();
}
function onOffline() {
    window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Check internet connection");
    //onClick event if defined only if the device is connected to internet, here is ignored

}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
     if(networkState == Connection.CELL_3G || networkState == Connection.CELL_2G || networkState == Connection.WIFI ){
      //open next page by clicking a button 
    }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Your code works fine. But where do you activate/deactivate the button? This checks only for internet connection if i'm correct

Answer (score 0):

Try 
if(navigator.network.connection.type != Connection.NONE){

}

Answer (score 0):

i changed the navigator.connection.type with navigator.network.connection.type and works now. 
For the activate/deactivate I have a function and I call it when the internet connection is active